Why my sticky position don't work like it should be?
<div className="bg-yellow-200 z-10 ">
        <div className="flex flex-row h-[1000px] ">
          <div className="flex flex-col gap-4 w-1/2">
            <div className="h-40 w-96 bg-green-200"></div>
            <div className="h-40 w-96 bg-green-200"></div>
            <div className="h-40 w-96 bg-green-200"></div>
          </div>

          <div className="w-1/2 bg-blue-400 z-50">
            <div className="sticky top-0 left-0 right-0  w-40 h-40 bg-red-500 z-50">
              <p>sticky</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>



I tried to make red box to be sticky in area of yellow box. but may be i wrote something wrong so it doesn't work. Please help me.  Thanks :)
I want the red box to stick at the top when i scroll down, and red box will stop sticky when I scroll pass the area of yellow box
Detail of what i want to achieve

Can you share more information on what you're trying to achieve? Your post doesn't really have much clarity on what you intend to achieve.

I've added more detail to the post.

are you sure its not working? h-[1000px] change it to a bigger number.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

I found what the problem is. I wrapped my code in the layout,when I comment out the style in layout it work fine
const Layout: React.FC<LayoutProps> = ({ children }) => {
  const ref = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);

  return (
    <div
      ref={ref}
   // style={{
      //   position: "relative",
      //   width: " 100%",
      //   height: "100%",
      //   overflow: "auto",
      //   touchAction: "auto",
      // }}      id="a"
    >
      {children}
      <Scene
        style={{
          position: "fixed",
          top: 0,
          left: 0,
          width: "100vw",
          height: "100vh",
          pointerEvents: "none",
        }}
        eventSource={ref}
        eventPrefix="client"
      />
    </div>
  );
};

export { Layout };

export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: Readonly<{
  children: React.ReactNode;
}>) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body className={inter.className}>
        <Layout>
          
          <SmoothScroll>
          <NavBar />
          {children}
          </SmoothScroll>
          <Footer2 />
        </Layout>
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}

Thanks for helping

The code provided does what you want it to do. The red box does get stuck to the top when you scroll down and it gets unstuck when you scroll past the yellow container box. I think you're unable to notice this because you do not have enough scroll area. So I added a new div around the content and gave it a larger height.
<div className="min-h-[2000px]">
     <div className="bg-yellow-200 z-10 ">
         <div className="flex flex-row h-[1000px] ">
               <div className="flex flex-col gap-4 w-1/2">
                    <div className="h-40 w-96 bg-green-200"></div>
                    <div className="h-40 w-96 bg-green-200"></div>
                    <div className="h-40 w-96 bg-green-200"></div>
               </div>

               <div className="w-1/2 bg-blue-400 z-50">
                    <div className="sticky top-0 left-0 right-0  w-40 h-40 bg-red-500 z-50">
                        <p>sticky</p>
                    </div>
               </div>
         </div>
      </div>
</div>

